# Best gem file to read a csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I need to read a csv file and fill in rows in jqGrid.

Which gem is the best to read a csv file?

I found csv-mapper and fastercsv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the version of Ruby you're on. I've been pretty happy with fastercsv on Ruby 1.8. And now on Ruby 1.9, fastercsv has been adopted into the stdlib, so no need to pull a gem, just `require "CSV"`.

Comment: require "fastercsv"
data = FasterCSV.read('C:\\Lalitha\\Bloomberg\\Rubian\\users.csv' )
puts data[0][0]

Comment: above code is not working.. I added the below line in environment.rb file <config.gem "fastercsv">

Comment: Without giving "require CSV", it worked. Thanks for all your help. the code is, CSV.foreach("#{Rails.root}/public/u.csv", {:headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol}) do |row|
      puts "#{row[:first_name]},#{row[:business_unit]},#{row[:ph_no]}"      
    end

Answer (score 0):

I've always used fastercsv, it's super simple to get working and doesn't require much code to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some unusual requirement that you haven't mentioned, Ruby's built-in [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) should do the job.